# WSAConnectByName alternative to allocate buffer manually?

Tags: c++, http, winsock

I'm in a sticky situation where I'm trying to connect to an HTTP server using Winsock.

I'm trying to leave 0 traces in memory while doing so which means each buffer needs to be allocated & free-ed by me.

I've come to the point where the last step of connecting to the HTTP server is using WSAConnectByName or WSAConnect, but the problem is, WSAConnectByName allocates its own buffer which means that if I pass my domain through it, the domain will be stored somewhere in memory and I won't be able to clear it using ZeroMemory.

Is there a good alternative to this? Gethostbyname isn't useful either since that function apparently allocates a buffer as well that I can't access.

EDIT: I should mention that the DLL is getting ejected out of the process, and even if it gets ejected, the strings (or traces) remain in the memory of the main process.

Comment: What is your motivation for not wanting any copies of your domain name in memory? On some level your program needs it, and whatever DNS service `WSAConnectByName` talks to will keep a copy of it as well (where it can be easily viewable by any user).

Comment: I am pretty much making a DLL that gets injected in to a program and I need HTTP requests to verify the licence. I just don't want the user to get a hold of the API. 

I can understand that it might be impossible to fully clear it, but i'm trying to at least make it harder for the reverser to find it. As of right now, you can even find it using process hacker using the strings menu. @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: Any worthwhile hacker will have Wireshark...

Comment: I already have certain checks for apps like these. @Paul Sanders

Comment: This is a battle you can't win. Even if you avoid allocations, clear all memory, etc. it will be trivial for anyone to intercept. Don't waste your effort: expose your API, but add some authorization to it so that you can track who is calling it.

Comment: The task is hopeless, see: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/69648-display-dns-resolver-cache-windows.html